# Applicative instance for hypercuboid

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I'm working through [extended abstract by Prof. J.Gibbons](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/apl-extabs.pdf) on APL-like programming in Haskell. I stuck with defining `Applicative` instance for hypercuboid datatype, though the paper states that it is perfectly doable. Simplified example is [as follows](https://ideone.com/9JnzJD).

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, MultiParamTypeClasses, DataKinds #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable (Traversable)

class (Applicative f, Traversable f) => Dim f

class Shapely (fs :: [* -> *])
instance Shapely '[]
instance (Dim f, Shapely fs) => Shapely (f ': fs)

-------------------------------------
--            Hypercuboid datatype
-------------------------------------
data Hyper :: [* -> *] -> * -> * where
    Scalar :: a -> Hyper '[] a
    Prism  :: (Dim f, Shapely fs) => 
                Hyper fs (f a) -> Hyper (f ': fs) a

instance Functor (Hyper fs) where
    fmap f (Scalar a) = Scalar $ f a
    fmap f (Prism p)  = Prism $ fmap (fmap f) p

instance Applicative (Hyper fs) where
    pure a = undefined 
{- `pure a = Scalar a` gives:
            Couldn't match type ‘fs’ with ‘'[]’
                  ‘fs’ is a rigid type variable bound by
                       the instance declaration
            Expected type: Hyper fs a
              Actual type: Hyper '[] a
-}
```

Recalling what is known about `Applicative` instance for `Vector n a` type (e.g. a list type-indexed by its length) I tried to think about `pure` as `replicate` (n-ary replication of a given value). But seems like this requires typelevel case (e.g. `pure a = case fs of '[] -> Scalar a; (f ': gs) -> <something using the fact that Applicative f>`) which is not avalilable in Haskell as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define separate instances for `Hyper '[]` and `Hyper (f ': fs)` (which is a sort of "type-level case".)

You can't define a single instance `Applicative (Hyper fs)` that behaves how you want because it would violate parametricity. Certainly I can define `isScalar :: Hyper fs -> Bool` in the obvious way; then what is `isScalar (pure ())`?

(Here, you wouldn't be able to define a single instance `Applicative (Hyper fs)` anyways for the reason that you will need a constraint on `f` in the `Hyper (f ': fs)` case.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do type level case, but you can do value-level case that reifies type-level information. Normally you define a singleton like this:

```
data Shapely (fs :: [* -> *]) where
    ShZ :: Shapely '[]
    ShS :: (Dim f) => Shapely fs -> Shapely (f ': fs)
```

and a type class like this:

```
class SShapely (fs :: [* -> *]) where
    shapely :: Shapely fs

instance SShapely '[] where
    shapely = ShZ

instance (Dim f, SShapely fs) => SShapely (f ': fs) where
    shapely = ShS shapely
```

This way the type class actually provide value-level information which allows to perform pattern matching like you want. I.e. you can now define something like

```
pureSh :: Shapely fs -> a -> Hyper fs a
pureSh  ShZ    x = Scalar x
pureSh (ShS s) x = Prism (pureSh s (pure x))

instance SShapely fs => Applicative (Hyper fs) where
    pure = pureSh shapely
```

The `ShZ` pattern match reveals that `fs ~ '[]`, so `fs` gets rewritten to `'[]` at the type level and `Scalar x` now is accepted. In the `ShS` case things work similarly.

However this doesn't really type check, because `Prism` also has the `SShapely fs` constraint which cannot be deduced from just `Shapely fs` (well, it can, but [not in a very nice way](http://ideone.com/zKhDK8)), so here is an improved encoding:

```
data Shapely (fs :: [* -> *]) where
    ShZ :: Shapely '[]
    ShS :: (Dim f, SShapely fs) => Shapely (f ': fs)

class SShapely (fs :: [* -> *]) where
    shapely :: Shapely fs

instance SShapely '[] where
    shapely = ShZ

instance (Dim f, SShapely fs) => SShapely (f ': fs) where
    shapely = ShS

pureSh :: Shapely fs -> a -> Hyper fs a
pureSh ShZ x = Scalar x
pureSh ShS x = Prism (pureSh shapely (pure x))

instance SShapely fs => Applicative (Hyper fs) where
    pure = pureSh shapely
```

`ShS` in `Shapely` now doesn't receive a first-order `Shapely fs`, but has the `SShapely fs` constraint instead, from which a `Shapely fs` can always be recovered. Now the types match properly.

[The code](http://ideone.com/iWcfLJ).